# Change color of nodes in groups option (vis.js)

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

is it possible to set the same color options in groups as in nodes? Only to pass the color as a string in `icon.color` works. But I also want to set *hover* and *highlight* colors.

I've tried the following:

```
var options={
  groups: {
    table: {
      shape: 'icon',
      icon: {
        face: 'FontAwesome',
        code: '\uf0ce',
        size: 50
      },
      color: {
        background: '#008CBA',
        border: '#008CBA',
        highlight: {
          border: '#5BC0DE',
          background: '#5BC0DE'
        },
        hover: {
          border: '#5BC0DE',
          background: '#5BC0DE'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
var options={
  groups: {
    table: {
      shape: 'icon',
      icon: {
        face: 'FontAwesome',
        code: '\uf0ce',
        size: 50,
        color: {
          background: '#008CBA',
          border: '#008CBA',
          highlight: {
            border: '#5BC0DE',
            background: '#5BC0DE'
          },
          hover: {
            border: '#5BC0DE',
            background: '#5BC0DE'
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Both attempts do not lead to the desired solution. The documentation states that all options of *nodes* that make sense also work in *groups*. Doesn't *color* make sense in *groups*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no implementation for `hover` and `highlight` for icons yet.

You can find more details in the related GitHub issue: [Color Icon Issue](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3526)